# setting an array element with a sequence while performing time series clustering

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfc2u.png)I am trying to perform a time series clustering.
and I don't know how to switch from the data structure shown on the image to the structure required by TimeSeriesKMeans.fit ( array-like of shape=(n_ts, sz, d) ) of tslearn.

Comment: please provide more detail and not in the form of an image if possible.
explain what you tried and  what is blocking you, provide a reproducible example of your problem, etc...
in few words: help protential helpers to help you.

Comment: Why are you trying to set an array element with a sequence?